# how to decrypt google chrome passwords

Tags: java, sqlite, google-chrome, encryption

hi i'm trying to get chrome saved usernames and passwords for sites but i can't decrypt the password_value at "Login Data" sqlite file.
i always get this error

> com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Win32Exception: Key not valid for use in
>   specified state

.
while decrypting the password

```
while (resultSet.next()) {
            System.out.println(resultSet.getString("origin_url"));
            System.out.println(resultSet.getString("username_value"));
            System.out.println(Crypt32Util.cryptUnprotectData(resultSet.getBytes("password_value")));
        }
```

Comment: Stack overflow probably isn't the best place to be asking for help on your malware.

Comment: Your not suppose to decrypt a password. Your suppose to encrypt the input password and compare it with the encrypted password from the database.

Comment: Plus you will need a lot more code then that trying to decrypt a password.